# Im wondering why my parameters aren't defined

Tags: python

I am sort of newer to python and I can't understand why my parameters aren't defined. I'm not understanding why parameters aren't global when I call the global function to the parameters, it says its already global. Here's the code

```
def Forum(Age, Sex, BirthYear):
    Age,Sex,BirthYear = input('Enter the following:').split()
    print('What is your Age?',Age)
    print('What is your Sex?',Sex)
    print('What is your Birth year',BirthYear)

Forum(Age,Sex,BirthYear)

print('You are '+ Age +' Years old. You are '+ Sex +', and you were born in '+ BirthYear)
```

Comment: What is the point in having `Age,Sex,BirthYear` parameters to `Forum` if you are going to turn around and ignore any passed values in favor of values obtained from `input()`?

Comment: read  [Python Tutorial: Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: `it says its already global`: Where does it say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong order. You seem to want this (with one input).

```
def Forum(Age, Sex, BirthYear):
    print('What is your Age?',Age)
    print('What is your Sex?',Sex)
    print('What is your Birth year',BirthYear)

Age,Sex,BirthYear = input('Enter the following:').split()
Forum(Age,Sex,BirthYear)
```

Or (with 3 separate inputs)

```
def Forum(Age, Sex, BirthYear):
    print('You are '+ Age +' Years old. You are '+ Sex +', and you were born in '+ BirthYear)

print('Enter the following:')

Age = input('What is your Age? ')
Sex = input('What is your Sex? ')
BirthYear = input('What is your Birth year? ')
Forum(Age,Sex,BirthYear)
```

This defines the variables for the function call itself; you are instead overriding your parameters within the function body, and making function-local variables, rather than global ones. You cannot define global vars within a function before they get used (by calling the function). Ex.

```
def SetAge(_age):
  print(_age)  # 2
  global age
  print(age)  # 0
  age = _age

age = 0
SetAge(int(input('What is your age? ')))  # inputs 2
print(age)  # prints 2
```

Comment: Where did the final `print` go?

Comment: Is it needed? All the values are still printed

Comment: It looks like the OP expected the ones with question marks to work as input prompts. I guess the final one is the actual, expected output.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why my parameters aren't defined.

This is because you did not define `Age,Sex,BirthYear` when you pass them into your function. Yes, you defined your function `Forum`, but on the next line you called it with 3 unknown parametres as your input.

While this is the reason for the `undefined` problem you are getting, as John Coleman mentioned in his comment, you should not be passing the parametres if you are getting them from elsewhere like `input()`. If you look closely, even if `Age,Sex,BirthYear` have their values, their values will be overwritten inside your function.